# How do you install a rosdep dependency under catkin/groovy?

Tags: rosdep, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've added these lines to foo/package.xml

```
<build_depend>mylib</build_depend>
<run_depend>mylib</run_depend>
```

and this to foo/CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS mylib)
```

and I added this rule to my local rosdep yaml file:

```
mylib:
  arch: mylib-syspkg
```

but when I run *rosdep keys foo*, I get a blank line, and if I try *rosdep install foo*, I get "#All required rosdeps installed successfully". A *rosdep resolve mylib* call prints out "mylib-syspkg".

If I run *catkin_make*:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:71 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "mylib" with any of
  the following names:

    mylibConfig.cmake
    mylib-config.cmake
```

It looks as if nothing is associating the *mylib* dependency with the *foo* package. Is there some new command I should run to install a wet package's rosdep dependencies?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49029/how-do-you-install-a-rosdep-dependency-under-catkin/groovy?/) by [Ken](https://answers.ros.org/users/13/ken/) on ROS Answers with karma: 438 on 2012-11-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like it's fixed in rosdep (but not released yet).

```
$ sudo pip2 install -I https://github.com/ros/rosdep/archive/master.tar.gz

$ rosdep keys foo
mylib
```

---

Originally posted by [Ken](https://answers.ros.org/users/13/ken/) with karma: 438 on 2012-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-11-24**:
0.10.9 released with the necesary patch.